# Solving a complicated multivariable function with Python

Tags: python, numeric, numerical-methods, approximation

I have a very complicated function of two variables, let's call them `x` and `y`. I want to create a Python program where the user can input two values, `a` and `b`, where `a` is the value of that complicated function of `x` and `y`, and `b = math.atan(y/x)`. This program should then output the values of `x` and `y`.

I am clueless as to where to start. I have tried to make the function into that of just one variable, then generate many random values for `x` and pick the closest one, but I have learnt that this is horribly inefficient and produces a result which is only accurate to about 2 significant figures, which is pretty horrible. Is there a better way to do this? Many thanks!

(P.S. I did not reveal the function here due to copyright issues. For the sake of example, you can consider the function

```
a = 4*math.atan(math.sqrt(math.tan(x)*math.tan(y)/math.tan(x+y)))
```

where `y = x * math.tan(b)`.)

**Edit:** After using the approach of the `sympy` library, it appears as though the program ignores my second equation (the complicated one). I suspect it is too complicated for `sympy` to handle. Thus, I am asking for another approach which does not utilise `sympy`.

Comment: Functions can be copyrighted?

Comment: Have you considered [sympy](https://www.sympy.org) ?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I have taken this problem from an author and though I don't think it is technically "copyrighted", I still don't want to put something which he came up with here without his permission.

Comment: @Ruan No, I have no idea how to use that. I would appreciate it if you could put an answer using that. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried plotting the function, to see what the beast looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You could use sympy and import the trigonometric functions from sympy.

```
from sympy.core.symbol import symbols
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve
from sympy import sqrt, tan, atan

y = symbols('y', real=True)
a,b = 4,5 # user-given values


eq2 = a - 4*atan(sqrt(tan(y/tan(b))*tan(y)/tan((y/tan(b))+y)))

S = nonlinsolve( [eq2], [y] )
print(S)
```

It'll return you a series of conditions ( ConditionSet object ) for possible adequate results.

If that wasn't clear enough, you can [read the docs for nonlinsolve](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#sympy.solvers.solveset.nonlinsolve).

Comment: When I run this code, I get the output `{(y/tan(5),y)}`. Why is this in terms of `y` and how do I fix this? In fact, it seems like the program just completely ignored the second equation!

Comment: Now, I get this: `{(ConditionSet(y, Eq((sqrt(I*(-exp(2*I*y) + 1)*(exp(I*(-y + I*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I)))) + exp(I*(y - I*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I)))))*(-exp(2*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))) + 1)/((exp(2*I*y) + 1)*(exp(I*(-y + I*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I)))) - exp(I*(y - I*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I)))))*(exp(2*y*(exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))/(-exp(5*I) + exp(-5*I))) + 1)))*(1 + exp(2*I)) - I*(1 - exp(2*I)))/(1 + exp(2*I)), 0), S.Reals),)}`. Is there still a problem?